# Django: update model field using button

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like to use a button to update a field (claimant) in one of my models (PieceInstance) and then redirect the user to a page where he sees all of the claimed instances.

The code is the following:

button:
(looping through all instances)

```
      <a target="_blank"
          method="POST"
          class="button" 
          href="{% url 'claim' pk=instance.pk %}">
          Claim
      </a>
```

views.py

```
def claim(request, pk):
    piece_instance = PieceInstance.objects.get(pk=pk)
    piece_instance.claimant = request.user
    piece_instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my-claimed'))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += [   
    path('myclaimedpieces/<uuid:pk>', views.claim, name='claim'),
]
```

It runs smoothly but does not update the field in the model and hence the content on the redirected page is still empty.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks almost good to me. The only thing is the use of `method` in a `<a>` tag makes no sense. You should either use a pure link:

```
 <a target="_blank" 
     class="button" 
     href="{% url 'claim' pk=instance.pk %}">
     Claim
 </a>
```

Or use a form with a real button (not a link formatted as a button):

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'claim' pk=instance.pk %}">
    <button type="submit"
        class="button">
        Claim
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great! The first suggestion works. I will also try to make the second one work, it just didn't happen to work when copy/pasting the code, I think I need to reformat it a little. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! I think it was missing a `>` in the `<button>` tag, should be fixed.